# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
import itertools

def get_flag(name):
    path = "flags/flags/{}.png".format(name)
    im = plt.imread(path)
    return im

def offset_image(name, xy, ax):

    xcor = (x_arg, x_australia, x_austria, x_bah, x_bang, x_bul, x_can, x_chile, x_col, x_cuba, x_cze, x_den,
            x_ecu, x_elsa, x_est, x_fin, x_gre, x_hun, x_india, x_indo, x_iran, x_ire, x_ita, x_jap, x_kaz, x_ken,
            x_kuw, x_latv, x_lith, x_lux, x_mal, x_mor, x_nz, x_nig, x_nor, x_pak, x_pan, x_peru, x_pol, x_qat, x_roman,
            x_rus, x_rwa, x_sau, x_serb, x_slova, x_slove, x_saf, x_skor, x_switz, x_turk, x_uga, x_ukr, x_uk, x_us)

    ycor = (y_arg, y_australia, y_austria, y_bah, y_bang, y_bul, y_can, y_chile, y_col, y_cuba, y_cze, y_den,
            y_ecu, y_elsa, y_est, y_fin, y_gre, y_hun, y_india, y_indo, y_iran, y_ire, y_ita, y_jap, y_kaz, y_ken,
            y_kuw, y_latv, y_lith, y_lux, y_mal, y_mor, y_nz, y_nig, y_nor, y_pak, y_pan, y_peru, y_pol, y_qat, y_roman,
            y_rus, y_rwa, y_sau, y_serb, y_slova, y_slove, y_saf, y_skor, y_switz, y_turk, y_uga, y_ukr, y_uk, y_us)

    xy=(xcor,ycor)

    img = get_flag(name)
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.72)
    im.image.axes = ax

    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy, frameon=False, xycoords='data', boxcoords="offset points", pad=0)

    ax.add_artist(ab)

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter',x='% of Ages 65+',y='COVID Fatality Rate', title='Correlation between % of Ages 65+ and COVID Fatality Rate')

for i, c in enumerate(df['Country']):
    offset_image(i, c, ax)

plt.show()
```

How do I fix this? Help me out y'all:( TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' I tried converting it into list but I can't split the list containing x and y coordinates:(

Comment: But there in the code I have not converted it yet, I did try already converting it into a list but still does not work :(

Comment: which line of your source file gives this error?

Comment: c:\users\ctc219-pc01\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_xy(self, renderer, x, y, s)
   1767             s1, s2 = s, s
   1768         if s1 == 'data':
-> 1769             x = float(self.convert_xunits(x))
   1770         if s2 == 'data':
   1771             y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: i think it's with the rendering of the image, the x & y coordinates are in tuples, but i tried to convert it into list and splitting it but it says list can't be split

Answer (score 0):

You get `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'` is because you pass the wrong argument type to [AnnotationBbox](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox) *xy* argument. Argument *xy* actually takes a tuple or a list with two elements as the location to be annotated. The first element is taken as x coordinate and the second as y coordinate. However, you pass a tuple of tuple, which means the first element is still a tuple. The error is thrown when it wants to take a tuple as x coordinate.

Below is an minimum example to reproduce your error:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xcor = (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
ycor = (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
xy = (xcor, ycor)
print(xy)

arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im = OffsetImage(arr, zoom=2)
im.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy,
                    xybox=(-50., 50.),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.3,
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

ax.add_artist(ab)

# Fix the display limits to see everything
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

To fix that, you could use `zip()` function to pack xcor and ycor into a list of tuple. Then iterate over this list to get each (x, y) coordinates.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xcor = (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
ycor = (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)

arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im = OffsetImage(arr, zoom=2)
im.image.axes = ax

for xy in zip(xcor, ycor):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy,
                        xybox=(-50., 50.),
                        xycoords='data',
                        boxcoords="offset points",
                        pad=0.3,
                        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

    ax.add_artist(ab)

# Fix the display limits to see everything
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]